# Call to undefined function mb_strlen() on PHP 7 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, yii2, ubuntu-14.04

I had a Yii installation that was working fine up until today. I installed updates on my machine today after which this error was being thrown on all pages:

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function yii\web\mb_strlen() in /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php:404

I ran `composer update` but the error persists.

I am using yii 2.0.7 on PHP 7 on Ubuntu 14.04. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error is a bit of a red herring since [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/mb_strlen) is actually part of the [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) php extension and not a function in yii2.

In php5 [`mbstring` was part of `libapache2-mod-php5`](https://askubuntu.com/a/491631/82817).

It seems to be missing from `libapache2-mod-php7`. To fix this install the `php7.x-mbstring` package where `x` is your version:

```
sudo apt install php7.x-mbstring
```

You may need to restart Apache after this install.

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache after the install

Answer (score 5):

### For PHP7.1

Debian flavours

`sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring`

RedHat flavours

`sudo yum install php7.1-mbstring`

Answer (score 0):

CentOS/RHEL-based

To get a list of available modules to check the version you need is available:

```
yum search mbstring
```

Installing mbstring module:

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

This will install the correct version for you for your current php installation.