# Call to undefined function yii\helpers\mb_strlen() on PHP in Yii2 Framework

Tags: php

I have an error occurred when i try run my project at the server.

It could not defined mb_strlen() in /var/www/html/amhadm/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseStringHelper.php

Here is my code in BaseStringHelper.php

```
 public static function basename($path, $suffix = '')
{
    if (($len = mb_strlen($suffix)) > 0 && mb_substr($path, -$len) == $suffix) {
        $path = mb_substr($path, 0, -$len);
    }
    $path = rtrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $path), '/\\');
    if (($pos = mb_strrpos($path, '/')) !== false) {
        return mb_substr($path, $pos + 1);
    }

    return $path;
}
```

Can someone guide me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function mb\_strlen() on PHP 7 Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756821/call-to-undefined-function-mb-strlen-on-php-7-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

The function [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) is not enabled by default in `PHP`. You need to install it manually. Check details here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

Install mbstring
For Php 5.6

`sudo apt install php5.6-mbstring`

For php 7.0
`sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring`